# What do I unmount in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a page wrapping `component` I am setting `state` in `componentDidMount` to handle `logging` authentication as

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
      authUser
        ? this.setState(() => ({ authUser }))
        : this.setState(() => ({ authUser: null }));
    });
  }
}
```

However, on some page renders I receive this error.

```
Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
```

Obviously, `componentWillUnmount` is what I need to use to unmount the component but what am I to unmount, the `setState` or `firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when your component unmounts, your firebase event `onAuthStateChanged` will still call. If it does call after your component has been removed (unmounted), then you will get your error.

In order to fix this, you need to cancel your event subscription inside `componentWillUnmount()`. You do this by calling the function returned from your subscriber. For example:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.cancelSubscription = firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged ...
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.cancelSubscription()
}
```